# Script Only Working On Chrome (Not FF, Safari)

Tags: javascript, tawk.to

I have a small script that hides the tawk.to live chat widget from a certian page. this script is only on a specific page and only hides properly on chrome, on firefox it sometimes hides there times it doesn't hide at all, and on safari it never hides) what can i can do get it hiding across all browsers? sorry for the noob question. any help is greatly appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Tawk_API = Tawk_API || {};
Tawk_API.hideWidget();

Tawk_API.onLoad = function () {
Tawk_API.hideWidget(); 
}
</script>
```

Cheers,

Brad

Comment: You are not showing enough code. Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your issue :)

Comment: `onLoad` events may be tricky depending on the browser and where in your code the script is placed. There's nothing wrong with the `hideWidget()` call itself (you can test it to your heart's desire on FF's console along with `showWidget()`). However, it could happen that, for instance, the onLoad triggers before the widget has been displayed, which will prevent it from being automatically closed. Having said that, there's quite a bit of code missing here to make a really educated guess

Comment: Sorry about not adding more code, I originally had it at the very bottom (its a large file) so I moved it to into the header section of this particular page & it stopped working all together.  (btw this is a c#/razor .net app) here is just the whole bottom section that *IS* working:

Comment: I tried to add more of the code but it won't let me (says its too long) its only like 10/15 lines.

Comment: https://imgur.com/eAomteE    here is a screenshot of the lines I was trying to add to show more code. thanks for any help you can provide. I tried to move it to the top of the page to load when the other JS loads but it didn't fire at all there.